# Highlight of code + RightClick list function (Comment Selection / Uncomment Selection)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Im working on a code-editor (windows form) and I just want to ask how to do such code as the RightClick function
inside a rtb . like in actual code-editor, when you highlight a specific line of text then you rightclick .
the line with highlight a listbox will appear with comment and uncomment and text with "//" for every line
if its "comment selection" but if its the reverse (highlight+rightclick the one with // before text) all "//" will
removed .

something like this:
[image]

thanks a  lot for the help in advance .really in need .thanks .

**<| ------ Updates ------ |>**

my current parameter for "//" function:

```
if (token == "//" || token.StartsWith("//"))
            {
                // Find the start of the comment and then extract the whole comment.
                int index = line.IndexOf("//");
                string comment = line.Substring(index, line.Length - index);
                rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Green;
                rtb.SelectionFont = new Font("Courier New", 10, FontStyle.Italic);
                rtb.SelectedText = comment;
                break;
            }
```

Comment: parameter added thanks .

Comment: You don't need `token == "//"` in your if statement. `token.StartsWith("//")` includes it also..

Comment: i know sir thats just a label for my code ... @SonerGönül